# React-native - LIbrary that can extract audio frequency, time and other infos like Web Audio API does

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio

I need a library that i can get this audio props so i can analyse those infos.
Do it exist? or some Android library that i can use in react native

Web Audio have this function: need something like this
If you want to extract time, frequency, and other data from your audio, the AnalyserNode is what you need.

AnalyserNode
The AnalyserNode interface represents a node able to provide real-time frequency and time-domain analysis information, for the purposes of data analysis and visualization.

Comment: Have you found something?